# Blazor css is not applied in Docker

Tags: css, docker, dockerfile, blazor-server-side

I have a problem with a Blazor app and Docker.
In debug, no problem with the css, but when I put the application under Docker, there is no css of my component.

To replay my problem :

- Create new app blazor server (name project : TestLib)
- add my little nugget package : [FanLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FanLib/1.0.0)

In `_Host.cshtml` add

```html
<link href="_content/FanLib/FanLib.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and in `Index.razor`

```html
@page "/"

@using FanLib

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<span>
    <FanButton TextDansBouton="Plouf" />
    <FanButton TextDansBouton="Plouf2" />
</span>

<FanComposant Nom="Lala" Id="12" NombreDeClickRecu="15"></FanComposant>
```

The button must be green, and the FanComposant its a card with .grow.

My dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestLib/TestLib.csproj", "TestLib/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestLib/TestLib.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestLib"
RUN dotnet build "TestLib.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestLib.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestLib.dll"]
```

I browsed the container, there is :

```
/app/_content/FanLib/fanLib.css
```

So why the css is not apply ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found. Its me.

I write

```html
<link href="_content/FanLib/FanLib.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but it's :

```html
<link href="_content/FanLib/fanLib.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

it's fanLib.css not FanLib.css ...